exporting a function and variable in React JSX
In my game wiki made with React JSX, there is an error:
 SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/components/Menu.jsx?t=1724725277296' does not provide an export named 'Menu'

but, the paths are correct (using CTRL-CLICK on vscode helps alot)
And where it exports baseURL  is exporting it correctly.
I tried in the Menu component to use parenthesis and square brackets, yet it didn't work.
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../assets/logo.png'
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:5173';

const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src={logo} alt="Moncria" height="192" /></a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active text-success" href={baseURL}>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active text-danger" href={`${baseURL}/wiki`}>Wiki</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active text-warning" href={`${baseURL}/users`}>Users</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active" style={{color: '#fc0fc0'}} href={`${baseURL}/register`}>Register</a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link active text-primary" href={`${baseURL}/register`}>Login</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default [ Menu, baseURL ]


Forgot to say this but I tried module.exports baseURL too

You should use curly braces when exporting

The error is correct, you've not any named Menu export, in face you've no named exports at all. Surely you meant something like export { Menu, baseURL };.

@Jayce444 I know

@Drew Reese I don't understand

What part do you not understand? The code doesn't export any variable named Menu. The code doesn't export any named variables. It only default exports an array.

Do u import like this?
import { Menu } from '/src/...';

Maybe try
import MenuConfig from '/src/...';
const [Menu, baseURL] = MenuConfig;


You can try this
export { Menu, baseURL };
...
import { Menu, baseURL } from './Menu';

